# In three more percent

Tags: riddle, word

1. In three more percent of my total life I will be half way of my living time.
2. It's nearly impossible to touch me but what can anyone do with me?
3. You usually call me with a very short word.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Sun

1. The Sun is approximately 47% of the way through its life (according to [NASA](https://pwg.gsfc.nasa.gov/istp/outreach/workshop/thompson/facts.html#:%7E:text=Existing%20for%20about%204%20and,into%20a%20small%20white%20dwarf.))
2. The Sun cannot be touched but can be seen.
3. Sun is a short word.

Answer (score -3):

You are a DAY.

At 11h 16m 48s you are  43m 12s away from your half life. If we add both we obtain 12h which is half of your life. 43m 12s is three per cent of the total life of a 24h day.

Secondly you can not touch a DAY.

Comment: Why would you start at that specific, arbitrary time? There's nothing in the riddle I can see which indicate such. Also, this doesn't address the second clue.

Comment: @bobble. I started that way because a day starts at midnight, 0h 00m 00s.

Comment: A day does stat at 0h 00m 00s. However, your answer assumes that the riddle's internal logic starts at 11h 16m 8s, and I don't see where that is indicated.

Comment: Still looks pretty arbitrary, though. Can you address what gave you this particular time?

Comment: @feelinferrety. A day has 1440 minutes. From this we can easily calculate three percent.  In addition to that we count the day starting at a particular time point, from 00h,00m,00s.

Comment: @VassilisParassidism Yes, that's how you get the 3%. And clearly days start at 0. But rather than extrapolate from the puzzle to get **YOUR** starting time of 11:16:48, you took the half that it WILL be and subtracted the 3% you calculated to get the starting time. There's not anything that indicates you should start at precisely the time you did. Only that you should end up at half. See the previous answer for a provably *current* timeframe that fulfills the numbers required.

Comment: @feelinferrety .I  did the opposite I calculated the three per cent of a day and I subtracted from the 12h.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis you're supposed to get to 50 from 47, not the other way around. In the other answer, the 47% is a pre-existing notion that is a current, observable, ongoing status. What is yours?